# How to use live reload in an express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I'm using express to make a server:

```js
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}`));
```

The server works successfully, however I need it to live-reload when I update the HTML file

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'd suggest to use nodemon to monitor your changes and reload the nodejs https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Comment: What do you mean live-reload?  Do you mean you want a browser page to automatically refresh when the page content is modified on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

next add a script line to your package.json

```
"live": "nodemon server.js"
```

now when you npm live it'll live reload

for more details see https://github.com/remy/nodemon

if live page reload is also needed

```
npm install -g livereload
livereload . -w 1000 -d
```

for more details see https://github.com/napcs/node-livereload